# JSON multiple alias names angular 8

Tags: json, angular

I have below interface.

```
interface ProductJson {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   price: number;
}
```

I want to have multiple alias names for price, like price and alias names: rate, etc. How can I read json data attribute 'rate' for 'price' and also read 'price' too.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean. so you want `obj.rate` to look up `obj.price`?

Comment: That's not JSON; that's an interface declaration. JSON is a text format. The object you deserialize from JSON may follow that interface.

Comment: Edited question.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to maintain a group of `attribute` names that you want to  alias.

And then add the interface property `price` to the `json` itself, if it contains the aliased properties like `rate` or `amount`.

Now you can simply access `price` from else where, which should give the same value

Ex:

```js
var price_group = ['price', 'rate', 'amount'];
var some_other_group = []

var resp = {rate: 200, p: 12}

var resp2 = {price: 300, p: 12};


Object.keys(resp).forEach(key => {
  if(price_group.indexOf(key) > -1){
     resp.price = resp[key]
  }
});

console.log(resp.price)

Object.keys(resp2).forEach(key => {
  if(price_group.indexOf(key) > -1){
     resp.price = resp[key]
  }
});

console.log(resp2.price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom serializer to create aliases between fields:

Example using [@kaiu/serializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kaiu/serializer):

```
class ProductJson {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   @FieldName('rate')
   price: number;
}
```

Or you can also create a getter method and use the serializert to map your JSON to a class instance in order to use your method directly, see https://kaiu-lab.github.io/serializer/ for in-depth stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you can do that tbh.

You can easily do it by programming your stuff that reads/writes the json to accept stuff like rate, price, moolah and just write it as 
{
    price: number
}

edit: what i'm saying is you take the user input or any other input that specifies something like {moolah: 30} and you take that '30' and put it on {price: 30} in your json.